# How to take panaroma in dslr?

Tags: nikon, dslr, nikon-d5300

I use a Nikon D5300 and while taking a picture from a hill I wanted to take a panaroma but could not find such an option. Am I missing some hidden feature using which I can take a panaroma? If yes what is that feauture?

Comment: Does your camera have the panorama mode? Did you consult the manual?

Comment: Here the question about almost the same camera: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/54723/how-do-i-shoot-a-panorama-with-a-nikon-d5200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such mode in D5300. Instead what you can do is:

Use a tripod, pan over the area and take multiple shots of the view of which you want to generate panaroma. Make sure you include slight overlaps in every consecutive frame.

Then use Photoshop or lightroom or any software you have to stitch them up as a panaroma. You can google about it or move to chat for more.

Answer (score 0):

NIKON D5500 TUTORIAL | Does It Have Panoramic Mode?

No, it does not. You have to do it manually. You have to use a tripod and take multiple pictures of the scene.

Please check out this link on YOUTUBE

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8no5jiHYbm4